# SQL display only 6 biggest values

Tags: sql, db2

I have this statement:

```
Select p_name, p_size 
from Part 
ORDER by p_size
```

So, now I want display only the 6 biggest values.
How can I do This with the IBM DB2?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select p_name, p_size 
from Part 
ORDER by p_size
FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause

Answer (score 3):

Google said:

```
Select p_name, p_size 
from Part 
ORDER by p_size 
fetch first 6 rows only
```

I've never used DB2, btw.